# Get the names of the images in the firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Right now i am downloading the images from the firebase by its name..

```
 storageRef.child("NAME OF your IMAGE").getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                    // Use the bytes to display the image
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
```

Is it possible to get all the names of the images stored in firebase storage to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. What can you do inseatd is to create a new section in your Firebase database named `imageNames` and every time you add an image to Firebase Storage, add to coresponding image name under this new node like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- imageNames
           |
           --- imageId1: ImaneName1
           |
           --- imageId2: ImaneName2
```

To get all those names, just attach a listener on this `imageNames` node and get all those names from the `dataSnapshot` object like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference imageNamesRef = rootRef.child("imageNames");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String imageName = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", imageName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
imageNamesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: can you please give me an example, how to get the names from datasnapshot  @Alex Mamo

Comment: Yes. Please see my updataed answer.

Comment: This is actualy for the database right? how can we implement it in the storage section.. i have 5 images in the firebase storage..@Alex Mamo

Comment: Yes, this how you add data into your database. You don't have to implement it in the Storage section. It's already in the database.